# how to add page number in react-native-html-to-pdf library pdf

Tags: react-native

i am creating pdf file using `react-native-html-to-pdf` library. i am rendering one table having 5 columns to 100+ rows of dynamic data i want to add page numbers on each page of pdf. how can i achieve this.

i tried using this code

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <style>
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #333;
            counter-reset: page;
        }
        .footer::before {
            counter-increment: page;
            content: "Page " counter(page);
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="body2">
                <table style="border: solid 1px;">
                .......
               
                 </table>
            </div>
        
        <div class="footer"></div>     
        </body> 
        </html>
```

but it shows page number 1 on all pages

Comment: This ```react-native-html-to-pdf``` library does not support the CSS ```counter-reset``` and ```counter-increment``` properties, which are used to manage page numbers.

Comment: how to achieve page number functionality in pdf using this library

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation how to implemented page number function in pdf react native

Comment: You should try use [pdfMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) then.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation I want to render dynamic data on the table [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) does not support react native

Comment: How about use [renderer](https://itsolutionsguides.com/tutorial/how-to-add-page-number-in-pdf-file-in-react-native)?